# Can we prevent users from updating the app with a new version from appstore

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app registered in app store and recently i have updated it with a new version 1.1 .The version is approved and its status is ready for sale.One of my user experienced a crash while launching the application after updating with the new version from app store.

I immediately removed the app from all app stores and its status is as "Developer removed from sale" which prevents any new users to download the app.

Requirement:
How can i prevent my current users (who purchased version 1.0) from updating the version?They are still able to update the app from purchased section in appstore application on ipad.

Is there a way where the user could not update the app until i upload a new version with the bug fixed.

Plz help with your thoughts

Tnx in advance.

Comment: If the version you removed is still visible on the purchase list from an iTunes account, please contact apple and file a bug report.

Comment: AppStore listing updates take their time until fully published - sometimes up to 48hours. Your removal might not be published to the store in question yet.

Comment: @J2theC the app is not visible in the store in general.But if a user has the app downloaded(older version), then that particular is able to update the app.I guess removing from sale only prevents new users from downloading the app..